# Three.js Change Mesh face colour using Raycaster

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am currently working on a web application that is supposed to give the faces another color when they are hovered over by a Raycaster (mouse).

I currently have a working .stl viewer and orbital controls in place.

To download and run my code with a known working .stl file [see my github](https://github.com/TjalleWired/three.js-stackoverflow). You can run it quite easily, only requiring a live server (which is easy to do in e.g. VSCode, see the [readme](https://github.com/TjalleWired/three.js-stackoverflow/blob/master/readme.md)).

It currently works perfectly with changing the whole object's color, but when I try to change the facecolor using the raycaster's `intersects` (the same way you change the object's properties), it does not work. I already read that you have to add `vertexColors:  THREE.VertexColors` to your material properties.

I can see the color value is changing (using console.log on the face's color property) and it changes to a different, corrosponding value when I change `intersects[i].face.color.setHex(0x0f0f0f)`. But the visual face isn't changing.

I think I am missing something or overlooking something, but I can't seem to figure it out.

My current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>3d viewer tjalle</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style/render.css">
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/mrdoob/three.js/r117/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/mrdoob/three.js/r117/examples/js/loaders/STLLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/mrdoob/three.js/r117/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>

    <script>
        function init() {
            var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
            var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
            document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, false);


            function onMouseMove(event) {
                mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
                mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
            }

            // Setup some basic stuff
            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xdddddd);


            // Setup Camera 
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 5000);

            // Setup renerer and add to page
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
                antialias: true
            });
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);


            window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

            function onWindowResize() {
                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

            }

            // Setup Camera Position
            camera.rotation.y = 45 / 180 * Math.PI;
            camera.position.x = 800;
            camera.position.y = 100;
            camera.position.z = 1000;

            // Add Camera Control through orbit.js
            let controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

            // Add some basic ambient lighting (Does light all parts equally and does not cast shadows)
            hlight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 5.3);
            scene.add(hlight);


            //Add some point lights to simulate real lights
            light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 10000);
            light.position.set(0, 300, 500);
            scene.add(light);

            controls.update();
            // Animation Script
            function animate() {
                raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
                // scene.children[2].material.color.set(0x1313)
                // calculate objects intersecting the picking ray
                var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children);
                
                for (var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++) {
                    // changes whole object to red
                    // intersects[i].object.material.color.set(0xff0000);
                    intersects[i].face.color.setHex(0x0f0f0f)

                }
                if (intersects.length > 1) {
                    console.log(intersects[1].face.color);
                }


                renderer.render(scene, camera);
                requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            }

            // Setup GLTF Loader and load in car
            let loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
            loader.load('example.stl', function (geometry) {

                // console.log(gltf);
                var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
                    color: 0x1313,
                    wireframe: false,
                    transparent: false,
                    vertexColors: THREE.vertexColors
                });
                var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
                mesh.castShadow = true;
                mesh.receiveShadow = true;
                mesh.position.set(0, 0, 0);
                mesh.name = 'Tjalle\'s Mesh'

                scene.add(mesh);
                renderer.render(scene, camera)
                animate();
                console.log("Scene: ",)
                console.log(mesh)
            });


        }

        // Call method for starting init
        init();
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The face property of the intersection object is read-only. Meaning even if you modify it, the actual geometry data won't be updated.

Keep in mind that you work with `BufferGeometry` which represents geometries via vertex data. There is no face abstraction like with the legacy `Geometry` class. So if you want to modify colors per faces, you have to ensure that no face definitions in your geometry share vertices. Or in other words, you can only do this with *non-indexed* geometries. Fortunately, `STLLoader` only returns non-indexed geometries.

The actual vertex color data are stored in a color buffer attribute. You can access it via `const colorAttribute = geometry.getAttribute( 'color' );`. You have to update the colors values in this buffer attribute to implement your intended feature. The pattern for this is:

```js
const face = intersects[ 0 ].face;
const color = new THREE.Color( Math.random() * 0xffffff ); // random color

const colorAttribute = geometry.getAttribute( 'color' );

colorAttribute.setXYZ( face.a, color.r, color.g, color.b );
colorAttribute.setXYZ( face.b, color.r, color.g, color.b );
colorAttribute.setXYZ( face.c, color.r, color.g, color.b );

colorAttribute.needsUpdate = true;
```

`STLLoader` does not necessarily produce a color buffer attribute so you might have to create one if it is missing.

Comment: I was on vacation, so sorry for my late reaction. Thank you for your in depth answer. The `STLLoader` indeed doesn't provide a color buffer attribute. But I think I am able to 'overlay' the mesh with the faces/vertices I need to see, to simulate selection. I think this will be an easier option than writing my own color buffer, altough I will look into that last option (Maybe I can even contribute a little bit myself to the great three.js project ;) ).